# How do I get a list of Search Templates in Elasticsearch 5.x?

Tags: templates, search, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

It appears the `.scripts` index no longer exists in this version, so I cannot just do `http:\\<elasticsearchserver>:9200\.scripts\_search`.

According to the docs, scripts should be in the `config\scripts` directory, but the `\etc\elasticsearch\scripts` folder is empty in my environment.  I have one template created at the moment, so it seems to me that something should be in there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found that when you add a Search Template via the API, it is stored in the cluster state, and you can get the list in `/_cluster/state` under `"metadata"`->`"stored_scripts"`.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the `"code"` under some of our templates were massive, obscuring the names of the templates, which is all I wanted.  This snippet will parse just the template names using the `jq` utility: `curl 'localhost:9200/_cluster/state' | jq '.metadata.stored_scripts | keys'`